# apache Header vs RequestHeader

Tags: apache, mod-headers

It seems that mod_headers directives `Header` and `RequestHeade` have the same functionality. It also seems that the only diference is that `Header` can read header information sent by PHP, while `RequestHeader` can not. is that right?

The documentation for `Header` says:

> This directive can replace, merge or remove HTTP response headers. The
>   header is modified just after the content handler and output filters
>   are run, allowing outgoing headers to be modified.

The documentarion for `RequestHeader` says:

> This directive can replace, merge, change or remove HTTP request
>   headers. The header is modified just before the content handler is
>   run, allowing incoming headers to be modified.

Answer (score 6):

It's not right. The difference is **request** headers vs. **response** headers.